# Pair SocketChannels in NIO

Tags: java, networking, nio

I'm trying to find the most elegant way of pairing two socket channels using java NIO. So far I am writing to one channel, reading from it and and writing the result to another. 
The way I'm going about it seems like a hack and I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way?

```
    public void readyChannels() {
    while (true) {
    try {
    selector.select();// block here until a new IO event
    Iterator keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();
        keys.remove();// do not process this again
        write(key.channel(),"random data".getBytes());
            byte[] bytes = read(key.channel());
                write(otherChannel, bytes);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make one channel the key-attachment of the other channel's selection key, or better still make an object that contains them both and set that as the attachment.